# Utf8JsonReader blocking UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to prevent user interface blocking by one of my methods.

method that blocks the UI looks something like this:

```cs
public void ReadJsonToTreeNode(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, ICollection<TreeNode> items)
{
    while (!complete && reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            // some recursive code
        }
    }
}
```

From what I've read I have two options:

1. use async
2. Task.run()

Async is not available for Utf8JsonReader so that option gets thrown out.
I've tried to use Task.run and similar methods but the problem is I'm unable to pass "byref types" to them and Utf8JsonReader is of that type. Even removing the "ref" from the parameter I still get this error.

I also tried creating a wrapper function but unfortunately it still blocked the UI. I think I did not do it correctly however because I wrapped the function that calls the blocking function and not the blocking function itself (unable to wrap that because of ref parameter).

```cs
public async Task LoadJsonAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(LoadJson);
}

private void LoadJson()
{
    var options = new JsonReaderOptions
    {
        AllowTrailingCommas = true,
        CommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip
    };
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath), options);
    jsonReader.ReadJsonToTreeNode(ref reader, TreeItems)
}
```

Are there any other options or is this just not possible using Utf8JsonReader?

Comment: "*I also tried creating a wrapper function but unfortunately it still blocked the UI*" - how are you calling `LoadJsonAsync`... if you called `public async void MyClickEvent() => await Task.Run(LoadJson);` it shouldn't block at all

Comment: @MichaelRandall I'm calling the wrapper just like `LoadJsonAsync();`, wrapper then calls the actual method using the await (see code snippet above). I believe that is equivalent to the way you suggested it being called with the click event? `ReadJsonToTreeNode` still blocks the UI

Comment: Are you awaiting the `LoadJsonAsync`? If you just invoke it like this: `LoadJsonAsync();` then you have a fire-and-forget task. You don't know when it will complete, and can't depend on its side-effects. Ideally the method should not have side-effects. It should return the resulting `ICollection<TreeNode>` directly after awaiting it: `ICollection<TreeNode> result = await LoadJsonAsync();`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am using caliburn.micro and calling the method from xaml view. I believe the await is handled automatically by the framework. If I try to make something trivial like `Task.Delay(5000).Wait();` it does work (meaning it doesn't block the UI). With sleep it also works without doing async await, just Task.run() is enough for the method to run async. However when executing my method the UI gets blocked.

Should this work even tho I am using Utf8JsonReader?

Comment: My guess is that your problem is not related to the `ref struct` nature of the `Utf8JsonReader`, but to how the asynchronous `LoadJsonAsync` method is consumed by the framework you use. But I may be wrong. I can't comment further because I know nothing about the caliburn.micro framework.

Comment: Understandable, I do appreciate your help thus far @TheodorZoulias